# CodeIgniter GroceryCrud set_relation same id in multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, grocery-crud

In GroceryCrud how do I set_relation using the same Id in diferent tables?

I want to do something like this:

```
$this->grocery_crud->set_relation('Id','Table1','Field');
$this->grocery_crud->set_relation('Id','Table2','OtherField');
```

But when I do this, it only work for the last value and I can't customize the label. How to achieve this goal, using multiple relations in diferent tables?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create drop-down list that would render as `Field - OtherField` instead your `Id` column, then you can:

Create a view in your DB which would join tables Table1 and Table2, eg:

```
CREATE VIEW Table1_Table2 AS
SELECT Table1.Id, Table1.Field, Table2.OtherField
FROM
Table1 inner join Table2 on Table1.Id = Table2.Id
```

And then include that view in your GroceryCRUD app:

```
$this->grocery_crud->set_relation('Id', 'Table1_Table2', '{Field} - {OtherField}');
```

Comment: I wish I could vote-up this answer more than just one. Wow! Not only is it an excellent answer, but as I had not heard of Views before, I learned something new from this answer that gave me solutions to 10 other problems! As they say, teaching a man to fish is better than hitting him with a fish. Anyway, one fine point I can add is to be sure to use $crud->set_primary_key to whatever your View has by way of a unique column.